# Flutter - How to get a Javascript callback in WebView?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, webview

I am using a `WebView` to load a local HTML file that contains the callback -

```
function onReward(data){
console.log("onReward: " + data.earnedThisSession);
Survey.postMessage(data.earnedThisSession);
}
```

This callback gets triggered when a user completes an action, I am currently facing two problems

1. The `data.earnedThisSession` returned by the function differs from every user and I want to get this as a variable in my dart code to reward my user
2. My `WebView` dependency is not printing console messages in my debug console

This is my `JavascriptChannel` -

```
final Set<JavascriptChannel> jsChannels = [
  JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'Survey',
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
        print(message.message);
      }),
].toSet();
```

This is my `WebviewScaffold` -

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: _loadLocalHTML(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(),
                    body: WebView(
                      initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
                        snapshot.data,
                        mimeType: 'text/html',
                        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
                      ).toString(),
                      javascriptChannels: jsChannels,
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    ),
                  );
                }
```

How do I use `evalJavascript` in this to fetch my reward data?

Comment: you are using stateful widget?

Comment: Yes @DarlanDieterich

Comment: @DarlanD. I don't undestand why you are writing comments without the context of the response. wtf it means try define a differente initialUrl for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Changing **Survey.postMessage()** to **window.Survey.postMessage()** may work. Im not sure how to use evalJavascipt with WebviewScaffold, i'm using like this:

```
final _webView = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
final Set<JavascriptChannel> jsChannels = [
  JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'Survey',
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
        print(message.message);
      }),
].toSet();
_webView.launch(url, jsChannels);
_webView.onStateChanged.listen((event) {
  if (event.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
    _webView.evalJavascript('Your Js Code' + 
    'window.Survey.postMessage("Your Return Mes.")');
  }
});
```